# How do I join two tables with different column in SQL Server CE?

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-ce

How can I joining two tables with different column in SQL Server CE?

I have two tables:

Table **Schedule**

```
+-----+----------+------+
+ ID  + Name     + Type +
+-----+----------+------+
+ 1   + A        + 1    +
+ 2   + B        + 1    +
+ 3   + C        + 2    +
+-----+----------+------+
```

Table **Description**

```
+-----+--------------------+
+ ID  + Description        +
+-----+--------------------+
+ 1   + A1 - XXXXX         +
+-----+--------------------+
```

And what I want to get is the table like:

```
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ ID  + Name     + Description     +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ 1   + A        + A1 - XXXXX      +
+ 2   + B        + -               +
+ 3   + C        + -               +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
```

Where the `Description` column should be filled in by `-` when the ID is not on the `Description` table.

I tried this code:

```
SELECT S.ID, D.Description 
FROM Schedule AS S 
INNER JOIN Description AS D
```

But resulted in:

```
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ ID  + Name     + Description     +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ 1   + A        + A1 - XXXXX      +
+ 2   + B        + A1 - XXXXX      +
+ 3   + C        + A1 - XXXXX      +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
```

And when I tried to give ON Clause:

```
SELECT S.ID, D.Description 
FROM Schedule AS S 
INNER JOIN Description AS D ON S.ID = D.ID
```

It just get the row where the `ID` is on the `Description` table, like:

```
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ ID  + Name     + Description     +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
+ 1   + A        + A1 - XXXXX      +
+-----+----------+-----------------+
```

How can I do that?

---

**[UPDATE]**

I tried this code and it works:

```
SELECT  S.ID, S.Name, COALESCE (D.Description, '-') AS Description
FROM Schedule AS S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Description AS D ON S.ID = D.ID
```

But now, how can I add a WHERE clause on it (pls see table `SCHEDULE` above)?

I tried:

```
SELECT  S.ID, S.Name, COALESCE (D.Description, '-') AS Description
FROM Schedule AS S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Description AS D ON S.ID = D.ID AND S.Type = '1'
```

But still get the whole rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server CE

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join the tables *Schedule* and *Description* on the key field **ID**. Also, use `COALESCE` to replace NULL values in Description column with `-`

#### Script:

```
SELECT          S.ID
            ,   S.Name
            ,   COALESCE (D.Description, '-') AS Description
FROM            Schedule AS S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Description AS D 
ON              S.ID = D.ID
```

#### Output:

Tested in *`Microsoft SQL Server CE version 4.0.8482.1`*

[image: output]

## With WHERE clause

You need add the `WHERE` clause after the *JOIN*s. If you are planning to having an `ORDER BY`, it should come after the `WHERE` clause.

#### Script:

```
SELECT          S.ID
            ,   S.Name
            ,   COALESCE (D.Description, '-') AS Description
FROM            Schedule    AS S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Description AS D 
ON              S.ID = D.ID
WHERE           (S.Type = 1)
```

#### Output:

Tested in *`Microsoft SQL Server CE version 4.0.8482.1`*

[image: output where]

Comment: Hi, it works. But the result is still not just what I want. Please see the code updated above.

Comment: No, it works now. But how do I add a WHERE Clause on it? Pls see the code updated above. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dccf/1

Query:

```
select s.ID, s.Name, Coalesce(d.description,'-') as description
from schedule s 
left outer join description d on d.id = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER`, and use `IsNull` or `Coalesce` to replace `NULL` values:

```
SELECT S.ID, Coalesce(D.Description , '-') AS Description
FROM Schedule AS S FULL OUTER JOIN Description AS D
ON S.ID = D.ID
```

Comment: It returns: `Token in Error = JOIN`. What's wrong? I tried `INNER JOIN` and it works, but when tried `OUTER JOIN`, it returns the message..

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/sqlce/thread/de5ab13d-3802-4d68-a1a8-6c66e51d99be

Comment: FYI `IsNull` is not an ANSI standard, and you should use `COALESCE` if in doubt.

Comment: @Ken White: I'm not sure why it works now. I updated the code above, pls take a look. How to add WHERE clause on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT S.ID, D.Description 
FROM Schedule AS S FULL OUTER JOIN Description AS D
ON S.ID = D.ID
```

`INNER JOIN` means select only rows that exist in both tables.
`FULL OUTER JOIN` means select rows as long as they exist in one table.

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN`...

Comment: It returns: Token in Error = JOIN. What's wrong? I tried INNER JOIN and it works, but when tried OUTER JOIN, it returns the message. My SQL is SQL CE on ASP.Net

Comment: @mrjimoy_05. Try `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: it's the same, but now get `Token in Error = FULL`.. >.<

Comment: @mrjimoy_05. [Read this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/sqlce/thread/de5ab13d-3802-4d68-a1a8-6c66e51d99be)